# Why there is so much difference in accuracy from fit model evaluation and confusion matrix by class. using R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am trying to interpret the results of the Random Forest model that I ran, by printing `Model_RF_RF`. However, these results look very different to the ones that I obtain by manually comparing the confusion matrix and the accuracy.

```
Model_RF_RF<-randomForest(Label ~ .,data = train.tokens.tfidf.df,ntree=500,mtry=82,importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE,trControl = cv.cntrl,nodesize=10)
>Model_RF_RF

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Label ~ ., data = train.tokens.tfidf.df,      ntree = 500, mtry = 82, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE,      trControl = cv.cntrl, nodesize = 10) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 82

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 44.56%
Confusion matrix:
       HIGH LOW MEDIUM class.error
HIGH     46   3     72   0.6198347
LOW       3  25     93   0.7933884
MEDIUM   22  20    194   0.1779661
> confusionMatrix(PD5,train$Label )
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction HIGH LOW MEDIUM
    HIGH    119   0      0
    LOW       1 120      3
    MEDIUM    1   1    233

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.9874          
                 95% CI : (0.9729, 0.9954)
    No Information Rate : 0.4937          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <2e-16          

                  Kappa : 0.98            

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.3916          

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: HIGH Class: LOW Class: MEDIUM
Sensitivity               0.9835     0.9917        0.9873
Specificity               1.0000     0.9888        0.9917
Pos Pred Value            1.0000     0.9677        0.9915
Neg Pred Value            0.9944     0.9972        0.9877
Prevalence                0.2531     0.2531        0.4937
Detection Rate            0.2490     0.2510        0.4874
Detection Prevalence      0.2490     0.2594        0.4916
Balanced Accuracy         0.9917     0.9903        0.9895
```

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Manu. The difference is that the result that you are shown within the call to `Model_RF_RF` is your OOB (Out of Bag) result, while the one that you print at the end is the result on your training set.

As you know Random Forests use bagging, which means that they use a bootstrapped sample of your data to grow the trees. This means that every single record in your dataset will only be used in a fraction of all the trees that you grow, i.e. those that drew the record during the bootstrapping. The OOB score is therefore obtained by predicting the entries using only the trees that did NOT include the specified entries in the bootstrap, therefore every tree only predicts data it has never seen - and this gives a good (often slightly pessimistic) estimate of your Test error.

It therefore looks like your training accuracy is very good, while your test one is quite low (as the OOB estimate suggests). You can try and test your model on some validation data or use Cross Validation, and you should obtain a score similar to your OOB one.

Try and change the value of `mtry`, increase the number of trees, or do some more feature engineering. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Davide. I got 61% accuracy on test data. Thanks for the explanation. it rise my second question can i accept model with this much accuracy?

Comment: Np Manu, glad it helped. Usually, if you find the answer useful you can vote up, or even choose it as solution if you feel like it fully answers your original question. On the note of accepting the model - it depends on your goals. If 61% is enough for you, then yes - i don't know the data nor the problem at hand. In general, I would still advise you to try and better tune your model, adding trees and changing `mtry`, maybe working on the original features a little. You might lose some time but you'll also learn a lot and you might improve your results!

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest not fixing the number of trees, but rather using an early stopping based on the OOB error (most implementations allow to do this): when the OOB error stops decreasing, the algorithm stops adding trees. This usually allows you to fit just about the right amount